# Bone Heat Weighting Failed, no solution works

Tags: mesh, vertices, vertex-weights

I've been trying to get the headband connected to the bone. The selected piece
I used Vertex Cleanup but it did nothing and deformed my mesh so I'm trying to find some solutions

[image: The Selected Piece]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably failing due to too much small topology. Try to reduce the number of vertices again. Or scale everything up so that more space exists between headband vertices.